# How do you read from pipe with both children in C?

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, pipe

```
int main()
{
    int pipefd[2];
    char buf;

    int pid, pid1;
    pid = fork();

    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(pid == 0){                    // CHILD 1
        close(pipefd[1]);

        while(read(pipefd[0],&buf,1) > 0){                       // THIS DOESNT WORK
            printf("FIRST CHILD WRITES: %s\n",&buf);             // THIS DOESNT WORK
        }                                                        // THIS DOESNT WORK
        close(pipefd[0]);
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    }else{
        pid1 = fork();

        if(pid1 == 0){                     // CHILD 2
            close(pipefd[1]);

            // while(read(pipefd[0],&buf,1) > 0){                 // ONLY THIS (WOULD) WORK
            //     printf("SECOND CHILD WRITES: %s\n",&buf);      // ONLY THIS (WOULD) WORK
            // }                                                  // ONLY THIS (WOULD) WORK

            close(pipefd[0]);
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        }else{                               // PARENT
            close(pipefd[0]);
            char* s = "Write To Pipe";
            write(pipefd[1],s,strlen(s));
            close(pipefd[1]);

            wait(NULL);            // WAIT FOR CHILD TO TERMINATE
            wait(NULL);            // WAIT FOR CHILD TO TERMINATE
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to run the program only the 2ND CHILD can read from the pipe, the 1ST CHILD never. So I tried commenting the second child's pipe reading, however the first child still can't read from the pipe to which the parent wrote into.

Why can't the 1ST CHILD read from the pipe?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see where you ever call `pipe()` to create the pipe in the first place?  It looks to me like `pipefd` is simply uninitialized.  Is this your actual code?  If you're going to cut your code down to a [mcve], that's fine, but emphasis on the "reproducible": make sure what's left still compiles (without warnings!), runs, and demonstrates the unwanted behavior.

Comment: Each byte written into the pipe can be read exactly once.

Comment: @NateEldredge woops yeah, I corrected that!

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, I get that but even though I don't read it with the second Child it doesn't work for the first...

Comment: Another problem is that you can't use `char buf; printf("%s", &buf)` to print one character as it is not a null-terminated string.  Use `printf("%c", buf)` instead.

Comment: You are calling `pipe` after you `fork`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is wrong.  Your code is

```
pid = fork();

if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

You need to create the pipe before  you fork.  You would probably catch this type of error if you check for errors on the `close` and/or the `read`.

Comment: But this demonstrate why is is best practice to *always* check for errors, even on functions that you *know* will work.

Comment: No, this particular error would not be caught by noticing a failure on close().  But it's a good idea to check, since that will catch errors in which the file descriptor is otherwise invalid.